# How to put an Image to the right of div inside a table cell

Tags: css, image, html

I'm trying put an image to the right side of a div inside a div inside a table cell:

[JS Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Sp2EP/5/)

In the example if you remove the below tag this is what the format should look like.

However when I add the img it changes the height of the entire cell and puts the image underneath:

```
<img id="close" alt="" src="http://customersupport.tikit.com/forum/custom/close_icon.gif" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correct , it's simple.

```
  #topback img{
    position: absolute;
}
```

By the way I don't understand why you work with tables, its so much more work than div's

**EDITED:**

Hope it's what you are looking for:
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Sp2EP/13/)

Comment: That certainly makes it look better, but i'm actually trying to get the image to the right of the title box centered vertically.